# How to precompile required js inside a coffee.js in rails for production mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

i have many js ,included inside of my admin.js.coffee

```
#=require jquery-1.6.1.min
#=require jquery_ujs
#=require jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min
#=require backbone_js
#=require plugins
#=require rails.validations
#=require jquery.blockUI
#=require jquery.miniColors
#=require jquery.MultiFile
#=require jquery.tipsy
#=require jquery.paging
#=require fileuploader
#=require plugins/jquery.guide
#=require plugins/jquery.blank_slate
#=require utils/utils
#=require_self
#=require ups_shippings
#=require fedex_shippings
#=require dhl_shippings
#=require backbone/admin
#=require jquery.dataTables
```

i precompiled it by

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w(admin.js)
```

but it not work , it only shows

```
<script src="//www.demo.me:4000/assets/admin-56aa0aed536032e816c31fa6a50e1872.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

what to do ?

in development mode:-

```
<script media="all" src="//www.demo.me:4000/assets/jquery-1.6.1.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and many more....

only link javascript will add , java scripts tag are not visible why ?

Comment: What didn't work? How do you know it didn't work? What did you expect to happen? What did you see instead that was different than what you expect?  You haven't given enough information yet for anyone to have any idea what's going on.

Comment: When i inspect my page js are not included.

Comment: Rails will precompile every dep in a single .js (here `admin-blabla.js`)

Comment: Yes precompile is done in public/assets all files are there , but doesn't show in inspect , also not apply on my page ...why ?

Comment: You've made sure it was pre-compiled, but that doesn't automatically put it on the page. You need to actually edit your templates that generate HTML, so they generate a script tag referencing it. Perhaps in your layout at ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, `<%= javascript_tag 'admin.js' %>`  Although the more normal Rails way to do this would not be generating a separate script tag, and not adding it to `config.assets.precompile`, but combining it into your single application.js file, with a `require 'admin.js'` in there. See the Rails Asset Pipeline Guide.

Comment: Means at application.js.coffee ?